# Automatically Download Zip files from U.S. Census Bureau

Tags: python-3.x, download, automation, zip

I want to download each state's legislative upper chamber zip file from this url.

https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2016&layergroup=State+Legislative+Districts

First, I want automatically download these hundreds of files to save time and effort.

Second, I want to save these legislative upper chamber zip files in the following format: us_state[0:]_upper_chamber_tl_2016_01_sldu_zip

Here is the link to the code that I so far have come up written. https://bpaste.net/show/9514161688ea

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui

#Step 1 Move to click on the drop down list of State Legislative - Upper 
#Chamber
uc = pyautogui.moveTo(1403, 671, duration=1.5)
pyautogui.click()

#Step 2 Move to click on the state in the drop down list.
al_uc = pyautogui.moveTo(1403, 700, duration=0.5)
pyautogui.click()

#Step 3 Move to the down download button
uc_dl = pyautogui.moveTo(1541, 679, duration=1)
pyautogui.click()
```

For those who are working with Python, I was suggested to use the "pyautogui" module. One needs to program where to click.

I encountered two problems.

(1) I had the automatic downloader in Chrome on. So, I had to turn it off so that it would not allow my downloads to pop up after downloading and messing with the code.

(2) I reduced the mouse duration speed from 0.5 to 1.5 when going to my target list from the download button. I did so because of my slow internet connection, chrome being slow at downloading, refreshing, and messing with the code.

Link to install pyautogui:
http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html